# String to float C#, odd result

Tags: c#, string, floating-point

In my code I want to convert a string to a float. But when I conver something like 49.5 to a float, it gives the output 495 instead of 49.5 how can I solve this?

`float.Parse`, `Single.Parse` or `Convert.ToSingle()`; give all the same result...

```
        String[] splittedLine = new String[25];

        splittedLine = foundLine.Split('-');

        float Z = float.Parse(splittedLine[2]);
        float X = float.Parse(splittedLine[3]);
        float Y = Single.Parse(splittedLine[4]);
        PointF Center = new PointF(X /2, Y /2);
```

the values in the `X` & `Y` are or a full number (example 207 or 49.5);
`foundLine` is a line from a textdocument.

So how can I that the value from the text file (49.5) will stay 49.5 instead of 495?

Comment: `float.Parse` will take that format without any special handling so I'm going to guess there is other code that is causing the problem. Can you post a complete running example? This should be pretty easy to reproduce in a small app.

Comment: use this after your string .Replace('.',',')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your system has a different format for fractional numbers than what your file was written with.

By default, `float.Parse` will use your system's locale settings to decide on this. To manually specify a format, you can use another overload:

```
float.Parse(splittedLine[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: CultureInfo is not working for me. Which library does CultureInfo need to let it work?

Comment: Found it. You need System.Globalization, It works! Thanks alot for helping me with this Theodoros :)